# Haskell - write zip function using list comprehension

Tags: haskell

My problem is that I want to write a function that zips 2 lists using list comprehensions. So far I wrote this:

```
import Data.List
zip' xs ys = [(x,y)| x <- xs, y <- ys, elemIndex x xs == elemIndex y ys]
```

but it doesn't work for

```
zip' [1,2,2,3,2] [1,2,3,4]
```

Any ideas how I should modify it?

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: Your function does *not* zip `xs` and `ys`... Why do you insist on using list comprehension, here, anyway?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need [parallel list comprehensions (seсtion 7.3.12)](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html) for this. In fact, this is exactly the example given in the manual:

```
[ (x, y) | x <- xs | y <- ys ]
```

Comment: Wow, you just taught me a part of Haskell that I didn't know. Documentation time!